# photos are disappearing in the Like box

Tags: html, facebook

I've just added the Facebook like box to http://www.papago.co.jp/
It seems to be working fine, except that photos are disappearing in the box 
We've changed from the default box width, but even at the default this was happening with our pictures. Is there any way to fix this?
Many thanks,

Lin

Comment: Can you reduce this to a simple code sample?

Answer (score 0):

the new embedded-post-plugin could be the reason why they dropped the image support... 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-posts/

btw, there are a lot of questions like this since july 2013. i've also contacted online magazines like t3n.de, and they have no idea why facebook is/was not reacting to it.

Answer (score 0):

This is "by design".  The limited space of social plugins like the Like Box and Activity Feed means FB has to display 'compact' versions of large stories like photos.  If you look at the CSS, you'll see the DIVs are tagged '!important' (not important).